# Spring custom query escape :

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, escaping

I have a custom query in Spring which look's like this

```
@Query(value = "select s.* from (select @p1:= :profileId p) parm , v_source_result_average_by_profile s;", nativeQuery = true)
```

The problem is that spring thinks after the first `:` there is a parameter but there isn't. Is there a way to escape the character?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by just adding `\\` like this

```
@Query(value = "select s.* from (select @p1\\:= :profileId p) parm , v_source_result_average_by_profile s;", nativeQuery = true)
```